# How to publish google sheet addon

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Addon not visible in Google sheet get-addons list (search)

I have published a google sheet addon. 
Also verified oauth scopes.
My addon is visible on chrome webstore ( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blockchain-for-sheet/gaajohppnkhndpfifhokefdeecgnbcih?hl=en&authuser=0 ) but not on Google sheets get-addon search result.

Google responded with my query as:

The reason because the item does not appear under the 'Get add-ons' menu in Google sheet is because the item is an extension.
Please review how the item is published since it is not published as a Sheets Add-on.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "NAME",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "description": "...",
  "icons": {
    "128":"logo_adOn.png"
  }
}
```

I have updated the manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "name",
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "description": "...",
  "icons": {
    "128":"logo_adOn.png"
  },
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Sheets",
      "serviceId": "sheets",
      "version": "v4"
    }],
    "libraries": [{
      "userSymbol": "cCryptoGS",
      "libraryId": "1IEkpeS8hsMSVLRdCMprij996zG6ek9UvGwcCJao_hlDMlgbWWvJpONrs",
      "version": "4"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": ["https://example.io/api/"],
  "sheet":{
    "name": "name"
  }
}
```

Comment: From which get-addon search you are referring to? Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: From google sheets Addons -> get-addons menu